# Query SQL LDAP import

Tags: mysql

I am doing an ldap import into a DB, the specific area of interest is the date created attribute.

Currently as per screenshot, this is in a long string and I would like to pick it apart so it displays in a date/time format. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYTgm.png)

The format I would like is DD-MM-YYYY all of the other information can be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Why export, ldap is a database, you can search this

On-topic:
In openldap this the field: `createTimestamp`, and it is presented in the following format
(20170531094335Z) -> 2017 05 31 09:43:35 Zulu time (utc)

The timestamp has the following format: YYYYMMDDHHMMSST. T is the time zone which is usually 'Z' (Zulu Time Zone = UTC/GMT)